# How can I retrieve COM+ Application information remotely?

Tags: c++, windows, com, com+

I'm fairly new to COM-related programming and I need a programmatic, C++ solution to the following problem. The remote machine has COM+ Applications on it. This information seems to be kept exclusively in a database maintained by Windows under %SYSTEMROOT%\Registration. The following code achieves what I want, but only on the local machine.

```
bool comslocal()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    TRY_HRESULT(hr)
    {
        CComPtr<ICOMAdminCatalog> catalog;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_COMAdminCatalog,
                              NULL,
                              CLSCTX_ALL,
                              IID_ICOMAdminCatalog,
                              reinterpret_cast<void **>(&catalog));

        CComPtr<ICatalogCollection> collection;
        hr = catalog->GetCollection(_bstr_t(L"Applications"), 
                                    reinterpret_cast<IDispatch **>(&collection));
        hr = collection->Populate();

        long count;
        hr = collection->get_Count(&count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
              CComPtr<ICatalogObject> object;
              hr = collection->get_Item(i, 
                                        reinterpret_cast<IDispatch **>(&object));
              _variant_t var;
              hr = object->get_Name(&var);
              std::wstring n(var.bstrVal);
              std::wcout << L"Name: " << n << std::endl;
        }
    }
    CATCH_HRESULT(hr)
    {
        std::wcout << L"FALSE LOL: " << std::hex << hr << std::dec << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Count: 5
Name: COM+ Utilities
Name: COM+ QC Dead Letter Queue Listener
Name: COM+ Explorer
Name: COM+ Utilities (32 bit)
Name: System Application
```

What are the exact modifications I need to make to this code in order to successfully retrieve the same information from a remote host? **Please** provide a working example if possible. There are many variables in play here and accurate documentation is pretty scarce.

Assume that I have credentials to a user account on the source machine and that the account is a member of the built-in Administrators group. The solution **must** make explicit use of these credentials as the code needs to work under various conditions in which implicit permission is not guaranteed. For the purposes of my testing I'm currently using a remote Windows Server 2003 R2 machine and its built-in Administrator account. My local machine is Windows Server 2008 R2, if it's relevant.

I have tried the following modifications:

```
    std::wcout << L"Connect" << std::endl;
    ICatalogCollection* pRemoteRootCollection = NULL;
    hr = pCatalog->Connect(_bstr_t(server), (IDispatch**)&pRemoteRootCollection);
```

However, the result of connect() here is always 80070005 (ACCESS DENIED). Impersonating the remote account via LogonUser() and ImpersonateLoggedOnUser() doesn't seem to help. I know that the credentials are accurate as I am able to use them to retrieve information from the remote registry and file system.

Feel free to propose an alternate solution as long as it is programmatic, C++, and doesn't involve uploading and running a script or process on the remote machine.

Comment: To create a single object on a remote system, call the CoCreateInstanceEx function, not CoCreateInstance. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686615(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Matt: I will investigate, thanks.

Comment: @Matt: Are you sure that "creating a single object on the remote system" is what I want to be doing in this instance? I was under the impression, given the existence of the connect() function, that I needed to create the object on the local system and use it to connect to the remote system. Attempting the method you recommended, I see a successful logon attempt in the source machine event viewer, but I'm currently getting 80040154 (class not registered). Still investigating the reasons for that, could be anything. A working example would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, you're creating a object one the remote system. I don't have any example at hand.